# UIscrollview delegation

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, delegates

I am trying to pass data between my two view controllers in my `UIscrollview`. I am trying to use delegation to send data between `Viewcontroller1` and `Viewcontroller2`. The delegate is `Viewcontroller`, while the delegator is `Viewcontroller1` and `Viewcontroller2`.

In the code posted below, when the switch in `Viewcontroller1` is toggled, it makes the switch in `Viewcontroller2` put to the "off" state. I keep on getting the

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

error when I run it, but I have no clue what is causing this problem. Any ideas why?

Below is the `Viewcontroller` that contains the `Uiscrollview` and the subviews/childviews

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, testing {


var vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)
var vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)



@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

func test1() {
    vc2.switch2.on = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)



    var frame1 = vc2.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc2.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

here is the Viewcontoller1 code

```
    protocol testing{
func test1()
}
    class ViewController1: UIViewController {

var delegate:testing?

@IBOutlet weak var switch1: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vc = ViewController()
    self.delegate = vc
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func switch1toggled(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.test1()

}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

and here is the Viewcontroller 2 code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var switch2: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func switch2toggled(sender: AnyObject) {
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

sorry for the long post, I have been stuck for a week on how to change the state of another switch from toggling a switch in another class, and this was the most efficient way that I found

Comment: You vc1 you are setting its delegate to a new, empty instance of `ViewController`, which won't have its IBOutlets connected, so you get a nil exception. You can't set a class's delegate from itself; the delegate needs to set from the delegate; in viewcontroller set `vc1.delegate = vc2`

Comment: @Paulw11 would you mind being more specific when I put          vc1.delegate = vc2  in the Viewcontroller class to get it to work?

Comment: @Paulw11 when I try to do the above mentioned code in Viewcontroller, int the func test1() i get the error "Cannot assign value to type "Viewcontroller2" to type "Testing?"

Comment: You need to declare that your ViewController implements the testing protocol; currently you have this on ViewController but that class isn't a delegate

Comment: @Paulw11 how would I make it a delegate, I thought I did by at the top of ViewController it implements testing

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake you want `vc1.delegate = self` in viewController

Comment: @Paulw11 would I put this line of code in the viewdidload of ViewController or in the func test1? - thanks for being so helpful, im new to swift and its awesome that you can help! :)

Comment: In viewDidLoad  function

Comment: @Paulw11 the program still crashes on the 2nd line it func test1() in viewcontroller :(

Comment: which is the initial view controller? and what methods do you use to transition between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

## ViewController1

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  let switch1Key = "view1Switch"

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    view1Switch.on = defaults.boolForKey(switch1Key)
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var view1Switch: UISwitch!

  @IBAction func view1SwitchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    defaults.setBool(view1Switch.on, forKey: switch1Key)
  }

}
```

## ViewController2

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  let switch1Key = "view1Switch"

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    view2Switch.on = defaults.boolForKey(switch1Key)
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var view2Switch: UISwitch!

  @IBAction func view2SwitchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    defaults.setBool(view2Switch.on, forKey: switch1Key)
  }

}
```

This method syncs the state of the two UISwitches using `viewWillAppear` and `NSUserdefaults`. The basic thought pattern is that you save the state of the switch to `NSUserdefaults` so that when either ViewController1 or ViewController2 is instantiated the view1Switch or view2Switch outlet's `.on` property is set to the saved value.

Caveats:

1. The first value for the switch when ViewController1 is instantiated (in the first app run) will be off because boolForKey returns false when there is no saved value. This can be hacked by using `view1Switch.on = true` directly after `view1Switch.on = defaults.boolForKey(switch1Key)`
2. This method makes the switches have the same value. In order to make them have different values, you can use a ! operator like so in ViewController2 `view2Switch.on = !defaults.boolForKey(switch1Key)`. This way switch 1 will always be the opposite of switch 2.

I recommend this method over delegation because, while delegation is powerful, its power doesn't seem needed here.
If you have any questions please ask! :D